# Strange artifacts in three simple objects & Problem in selections in edit mode

Tags: rendering, edit-mode, eevee-render-engine, selection-tools, artifacts

[image]

I have found a problem with these simple meshes that have all the same artifacts.
They are just cubes with subdivision modifier already applied.

With or without materials, it is the same. The problem appears only through the camera (whatever mode: solid, material or rendered modes) and eevee renders.
I have deleted and created other shapes with the same problem. the three current ones still show the disgrace.

Clicking on backface culling seems to make a difference, but could cause other problems, and only changes the camera mode, not the eevee render that remains the same. I want to know what is causing the problem.
Changing from perspective to ortographic camera, also works, but in my case is useless.

I use the 2.91 version.

Also I am experiencing a problem with selection in edit mode, so I reinstalled the program, but still am experiencing this.
It is that in edit mode, with x-ray toggle button ON I can't select vertices and faces, only edges. X-ray button activates backface culling and x-ray, when I disable it I can't see what I am doing so I can't just model without being able to use it.
I put it in the same question in case that for some weird reason they relate to each other.

Here some images about the first problem, the artifacts.

[image: the normal things]

out of camera: everything normal

[image: out of camera: you can see the position of the vertices and the mirror modifier]

out of camera: you can see the position of the vertices and the mirror modifier

[image: through the camera lens]

through the camera: the vertices seem to be in a strange position, not to the side (-x) of the shape but front. while both proto-eyes remain where they should be, but also with artifacts.

[image: backface culling]
through the camera: with backface culling

[image: cycles render]

Cycles render

[image: closeup]

Close-up

I searched other questions, with different terms, but couldn't find an answer. Have just started out a month ago, done the chair modelling tutorial from blender guru. Here I was trying to make a head.

---

It seems that creating another blender scene, opening both and ctrl+c the shapes I wanted to salvage, ctrl+v to the newer has worked.
Maybe the scene was bugged? I provided the file in the question and I am curious if someone has experienced the same problems.
Still WTH has happened?

Comment: Maybe clipping values for the camera were not appropriate. Select the camera > Properties editor > Object data tab > Lens > Clip Start and End can be changed so that minimal is not too small however allowing to see near objects and far isn't too big. Usually difference shouldn't be higher that 0,01 and 1000, for example

Comment: @MrZak Changing clipping settings did solve the artifacts problem, thank you. I read in another post that changing it could help, but I ended up increasing the range. There is still no answer to the problem selecting in edit mode, though. I ended up copying and pasting the shapes to a new file.